# How to fix mysqli_query() and mysqli_fetch_array() errors

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to make a PHP script that prints text from file to website on button click.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "dbname");
    if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
        mysqli_query("SELECT name,lastname FROM users ORDER BY RAND()");
        $name = null;
        $lastname = null;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array()) {
            $name = $row['name'];
            $lastname = $row['lastname'];
        }
        echo '<p><small>Output:</small></p><pre style="min-width:auto;display:table;">' . $name . '_' . $lastname . '</pre>Format: <b>name_lastname</b> <span style="width:310px;">';
    }
?>
<form method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="button">button</button>
    <br>
</form>
```

And this is the error that I get every time when the button is clicked:
[image: image of error]

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: `mysqli_query()` need first parameter as your database connection. Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: By the looks of your first error. You need to deal with MySql access permission or your connection parameter are provided wrongly e.g: incorrect username or password

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very
helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be
copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well,
meaning that other users with the same problem are less
likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to
incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using
copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to introduce database connection variable which most mysqli_* functions required, `$con` in your modified script:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "dbname") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name,lastname FROM users ORDER BY RAND()");
        $name = null;
        $lastname = null;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $name = $row['name'];
            $lastname = $row['lastname'];
        }
        echo '<p><small>Output:</small></p><pre style="min-width:auto;display:table;">' . $name . '_' . $lastname . '</pre>Format: <b>name_lastname</b> <span style="width:310px;">';
    }
?>
<form method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="button">button</button>
    <br>
</form>
```

In addition you need to pass  result set identifier returned by mysqli_query(), `$result` in that case. Everything can be found at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp).

Answer (score 0):

**First Error**

1. You need to make sure you have access permission to your `MySql`
2. Make sure you have provided all the correct values for all the parameters (host,username,password,dbname) in

   `mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "dbname");`

**Second Error**
is in

`mysqli_query("SELECT name,lastname FROM users ORDER BY RAND()");`
`mysqli_connect` takes two parameters `dbconnection` & `query`. Refer [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

**Third Error** in `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array()) {`

`mysqli_fetch_array()`  expects atleast 1 parameter (eg. result return by your     `mysqli_query()`. Check this [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

**MODIFIED CODE**

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "dbname") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
        $result =  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name,lastname FROM users ORDER BY RAND()");
        $name = null;
        $lastname = null;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $name = $row['name'];
            $lastname = $row['lastname'];
        }
        echo '<p><small>Output:</small></p><pre style="min-width:auto;display:table;">' . $name . '_' . $lastname . '</pre>Format: <b>name_lastname</b> <span style="width:310px;">';
    }
?>
<form method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="button">button</button>
    <br>
</form>
```